# Need suggestion for API and GUI test automation tool

Tags: testing, automation

I have been going through many tool, but not able to conclude.
I have been using HP UFT for sometime and it's quite OK for my project but for some reason we need to find alternative to HPUFT with some advantage.

I have been exploring tool like selenium, IBM tools.soap ui
Could anyone suggest me test automation tool with advantages , so that I can explore.

My scenario,
More REST API based validation.
Need to make REST call and parse the response for validation.

Comment: Would something like QuickTest (HP, former Mercury) would do?

Comment: Yes, I have been using the same but rest response validation is pain, by validating the XML via xslt etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, it all depends on if you are comfortable coding then you can use REST ASSURED if you are not too comfortable with coding then there are tools like POSTMAN and Ready API (SOAPUI) Which you can automate with very well which comes with loads of assertions.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources / recommendations / links are off-topic for SO. They should be flagged/closed, not answered

Answer (score 1):

Since you are testing REST API and validating result, I would not any testing related to UI here. So Selenium ruled out if there is no web UI involved.

For rest API I would recommend you can use Java with Junit/TestNG. Where you write keywords in Java and use the same ones to write Junit/TestNG tests.

Another alternative could be RobotFramework, for which u can have keywords in python.